# Do we have $\int_0^t \frac{1}{2}tr(e^{\int_0^v f(u)Idu})dv=\int_0^te^{\int_0^vf(u)du}dv? $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, matrices

If $I$ is a 2 by 2 identity matrix, do we have
$$
\int_0^t \frac{1}{2}tr(e^{\int_0^v f(u)Idu})dv=\int_0^te^{\int_0^vf(u)du}dv?
$$
where $tr$ is the trace of the matrix.

How to understand this integral of a matrix? I know that
$$
\int_0^v f(u)Idu=\begin{bmatrix}
\int_0^v f(u)du & 0 \\
0 & \int_0^v f(u)du
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But what is $tr(e^{\int_0^v f(u)Idu})=$?

Comment: $tr(e^{\int_0^v f(u)Idu})=\int_0^v f(u)du+\int_0^v f(u)du=2\int_0^v f(u)du.$

Comment: @Fred Why the first equality holds? Is there exp of this integral?

Comment: sorry, my comment is nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and this works in any dimension $d$. Let $g = g(v) = \int_0^v f$. Then
$$
e^{\int_0^v f(u)\,I\,\mathrm d u} = e^{g\, I} = e^g\, I
$$
This is because taking the exponential of a diagonal matrix is the same as taking the exponential on each of its diagonal coefficients. Therefore
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(e^{\int_0^v f(u)\,I\,\mathrm d u}) = d\, e^{-g}.
$$